# How can I replace spaces with carriage returns using PHP?

Tags: php, string

I have a few strings

```
Computer Stations
Monitors
Indian Reserve
```

How do i replace spaces in a variable with carriage returns `"\r"`?  How can I determine if a replacement was made so I can add a CSS class in my output.

My PHP is below and basically for CSS purposes i need to force a carriage return on two words and if the string is a single word then give the class "single" so i can style it differently...any ideas

```
$key "Computer Stations"
echo "<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"cat cat-btn  lf\">{$key}</a></li>";
$key "Monitors"
echo "<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"cat cat-btn single lf\">{$key}</a></li>";
$key "Indian Reserve"
echo "<li><a href=\"#\" class=\"cat cat-btn  lf\">{$key}</a></li>";
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear (to me anyway), but I think you're looking for either strpos or str_replace.

Comment: ok so i need to force a break when there is a space

Comment: and do you mean a line break or a html <br> tag?

Comment: So you want to replace any spaces with a `<br>` so the two words will be forced onto two lines when viewed with a web browser?

Comment: http://us.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php might be of help in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code will replace all spaces with return symbol (`"\r"`) and if there isn't any, set variable `$class` to `"single"`.

```
$newString = str_replace(" ", "\r", $oldString, $count);
if($count == 0) {
   $class = "single";
}

echo "<li><a class=\"$class\">$newString</a></li>";
```

By return you mean newline? If so, you should use `"\n"` instead of `"\r"`. If you would like to see the newline in a browser not just in the code you should use `'<br />'` instead.

Comment: `<br/>`, not `<br\>`; as well as `\r` not `/r` in the question.. :)

Comment: I believe the `/r` in the question was a typo as well as the `<br \>` in the answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly:

```
if (strpos($str, ' ') !== false) { 
    // there is space in string, do something
}
```

If you want to replace space to something:

```
str_replace(' ', "\n", $string);
```

In this case str_replace replaces every space to newline symbol.

Answer (score 2):

To check presence of any string inside another, use the PHP [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function:

```
if (strpos($key, " ") !== FALSE) {
    // There is a space
}
else {
    // No space in string
}
```